# wifi on toshiba laptop with rtl8192ce driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, laptop, realtek, toshiba

I am wondering if there is a standard fix that works for the wifi in trusty tahr.  I have a toshiba satellite L755 with the realtek rtl8188ce wireless adapter.  I installed 14.04  three weeks ago and crashed and burned for hours and hours and days and days of effort, trying many recommended fixes with no success and spending way too much time on a wifi driver problem. Disappointed, I am now back to 13.10 on this laptop, for now.

I am wondering if this problem in trusty tahr has been definitively fixed yet, and if so, I am seeking one clear set of steps/directions that will get the wireless adapter working in trusty tahr, before I upgrade again.  TIA.

Comment: Please describe the problems you are having in more detail and the steps you have taken to fix them.  The rtl8192ce driver is fully functioning on current Ubuntu distributions.

Comment: Also have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos for general Wifi troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=Y ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf` has been a reliable fix after a reboot